# Postgresql Order by based on specific values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column called `item_priority`
Which has following values `'important', 'super_important', 'important_1', 'important_2'`

I want to order the result in a way where the following items

```
'important', 'super_important', 'important_1', 'important_2'
```

Appear in order.

This is my query, it appears that `important_2` appears before `important_1`, currently.

```
SELECT * from 
main_table
where product_id = '200'
ORDER BY col1, col2, CASE WHEN item_priority ~ '^[a-zA-Z]' THEN 1 WHEN WHEN item_priority~ '^[0-9]' THEN 2 END, item_priority desc, col3
```

Answer (score 2):

Ordering by an array will be especially slow.

Just use a valued CASE like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   main_table
WHERE  product_id = '200'
ORDER  BY col1, col2, 
          CASE item_priority 
             WHEN 'important' THEN 1
             WHEN 'super_important' THEN 2
             WHEN 'important_1' THEN 3
             WHEN 'important_2' THEN 4   
          END;
```

En fact, valued CASE is quicker than any other forms of ordering...

Comment: That unfortunately didn't really change the order. I.e important shows last before anything.

Answer (score 1):

ORDER BY supports arbitrary expressions. [`array_position()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) will do what you're looking for, making the final clause `ORDER BY array_position(['important', 'super_important', 'important_1', 'important_2'], item_priority)`.

Comment: I am running into syntax issues. :  `syntax error at or near "["
LINE 45:         ORDER BY array_position([ `

I added `ARRAY` before that and now  I am getting HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
This is what I ended up with `ORDER BY array_position(ARRAY['important', 'super_important', 'important_1', 'important_2'], item_priority) , col1, col2, col3`